# MySQL - How to perform a multiple join query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I am trying to join two tables but the problem is that the cashiers table could be joined with 3 fields from the sales table and I don’t want to miss any record if I join both tables just with one field. I only want to get as many rows as the cashiers table has. I hope that makes sense. This is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
SELECT cashiers.cashierId,cashiers.name,cashiers.age, 
(SELECT
(SELECT SUM(amount) * .20 FROM sales WHERE cashierId1 = cashiers.cashierId) + 
(SELECT SUM(amount) * .30 FROM sales WHERE cashierId2 = cashiers.cashierId) +
(SELECT SUM(amount) * .40 FROM sales WHERE cashierId3 = cashiers.cashierId)
) AS totalAmount
FROM cashiers
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Sample data would really help clarify what you are doing.

Comment: you can join on multiple fields at once.  `select * from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.column1 = b.column1 and a.col2 = b.col2`

Comment: Will each sale count toward exactly one cashier?

Comment: Many cashierID columns is very likely bad design. (Thus the resulting needless complexity of your query & table predicate.) Just have one cashierID column & record rows where "*cashierID* did sale *saleID* AND ...". We must guess until you give such a predicate  for your current table. Eg "sale *saleID* ... AND (no cashier did it AND *cashierID1*, *cashierID2* & *cashierID3* are NULL OR only *cashierID1* did it AND *cashierID2* & *cashierID3* are NULL OR only *cashierID1* and *cashierID2* did it and *cashierID3* IS NULL OR only *cashierID1* and *cashierID2* and cashierIDI3* did it) AND ...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Gordon's answer is probably good but I think it also assumes that only one of the cashiers is going to match. You may have been imagining something more like this:

```
select
    c.cashierid, min(c.name) as name, min(c.age) as age,
    sum(s1.amount * 0.2) + sum(s2.amount * 0.3) + sum(s3.amount * 0.4)
from
    cashiers c
    left outer join sales s1 on s1.cashierid1 = c.cashierid
    left outer join sales s2 on s2.cashierid2 = c.cashierid
    left outer join sales s3 on s3.cashierid3 = c.cashierid
group by
    c.cashierId
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT c.cashierId, c.name, c.age, 
       (SELECT SUM(CASE c.cashierId WHEN s.cashierId1 THEN 0.2 * s.amount
                                    WHEN s.cashierId2 THEN 0.3 * s.amount
                                    WHEN s.cashierId3 THEN 0.4 * s.amount
                   END)
        FROM sales
        WHERE c.cashierId IN (s.cashierId1, s.cashierId2, s.cashierId3)
       ) AS totalAmount
FROM cashiers c;
```

Comment: You need the `case` inside the summation. I think that was just an accident though.